# update two tables rows by id through transaction

Tags: php, sql, join, parameters

How do I select two tables and join them by id's for an update through a transaction?
I tried with prep stmts but the id's just wont work as a parameter....
can transactions do it?

```
// submit
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
  // Edit ID
  if (isset($_GET['edit'])) 
  $ID = $_GET['edit'];       
  // form input 
  if (isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['director'], $_POST['year'], $_POST['genre'])) 
  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $director = $_POST['director'];
  $year = $_POST['year'];
  $category = $_POST['genre'];      

  // required
  if ( $title == '' || $director == '' || $year == '' ||$category == '')
   {
   // generate error message
   $error = 'Fält saknas!';
   // if either field is blank, display the form again
   renderForm($category, $title, $director, $year, $error);
   }
  else {  
  // Edit 
  // auto turn off
   mysqli_autocommit($conn,FALSE);
   // values
   mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO movies (title, director, year) 
   VALUES ('$title', '$director', '$year') WHERE ID = '$ID'");
   mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO category (category) 
   VALUES ('$category') WHERE ID = '$ID'");
   // Commit transaction
   mysqli_commit($conn);

     echo "<div class='receipt'>Register ".$ID." uppdaterat.<br>
     <a href='index.php'>Gå tillbaka</a> </div>";
             }
} $conn->close();
```

Comment: *tried with prep stmts but the id's just wont work as a parameter* ... why is that? Where is the attempt at prep statements?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL your write maybe not collect,  you must first run it in an SQL client first to test the SQL grammar.

If you use MySQL, the collect way must be something like this:

```
UPDATE movies m
INNER JOIN category c ON
    m.id = m.id
SET title=?, director=?, year=?, genre =?
WHERE id =?
```

BTW, the `inner join` maybe not necessary, see your needs.

Again, you must test the structure first and only if it is collected then embed it to other languages.

**EDITED**

How to use prepared statement in a MySQL client:

```
mysql> PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'SELECT SQRT(POW(?,2) + POW(?,2)) AS hypotenuse';
mysql> SET @a = 3;
mysql> SET @b = 4;
mysql> EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a, @b;
+------------+
| hypotenuse |
+------------+
|          5 |
+------------+
mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: well the problem is not really the sql syntax its the statement parameters: I want to join the table id's and update the row where the id is the (?) ($ID) also adding the other parameters.

Comment: wekk how do I make a prep stmt in the terminal? the prep stmt query is for php